# Use Update and Join together between three tables

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I have a database in a rails app that is linked as follows:
Person knows its School which knows it's School Rules.

I'm trying to write a migration that creates a CanDoThis column in Person and populates it with the relevant IsThisAllowed column in School Rules. 
This is what I have so far but its giving me a "table name "school_rules" specified more than once" error.

```
UPDATE people
  SET people.canRunInHalls = school_rules.RunningInHallsIsAllowed 
  FROM school_rules
  JOIN school_rules on school_rules.school_id = schools.id 
  JOIN schools ON schools.id = people.school_id;
```

Tried something new - got this error: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "people"

HINT:  There is an entry for table "people", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

```
UPDATE people
  SET people.canRunInHalls = school_rules.RunningInHallsIsAllowed 
  FROM schools s
  JOIN school_rules on school_rules.school_id = s.id 
  JOIN schools ON schools.id = people.school_id;
```

EDIT: attempt at drawing the schema

```
people
-------------
id
school_id
canRunInHalls


schools
_______________
id
people
school_rules_id


school_rules
_______________
id
school_id
RunningInHallsIsAllowed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with better aliases:

```
UPDATE p
  SET canRunInHalls = sr.RunningInHallsIsAllowed 
  FROM people p
  INNER JOIN school_rules sr ON p.school_id = sr.school_id;
```

Since you don't actually need anything from schools, I removed it from the statement.

As a warning, I think you are going to run into trouble with the many to many.  Since a school can have many rules, you aren't being clear as to which school_rule is going to apply to the person.  You may need to aggregate school_rules, or use some descriptor to restrict it down to 1 row.

Comment: Tried that but then it gave me a 'schools' has been specified twice. (i had to replace projects with schools.)

Comment: Well yeah, I didn't see that.  You joined to PROJECTS, but then neither column in your join actually joined to PROJECTS.  That's not good.  I edited my answer, but without seeing your schema I'm flying blind.

Comment: can you take a look at my edit? projects was replaced with schools, people is still there. I'll try to describe the schema better.

Comment: thanks - out of curiosity, how would one go about it if school_rules doesn't have a school_id column?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by aggregate school_rules?

Comment: There are MANY school rules for each person.  You should decide whether if just ONE of those rules has RunningInHallIsAllowed does that mean the person can run in the halls, or do ALL of the rules need to have RunningInTheHallsAllowed.  You are setting 1 thing to many things.  That's awkward, and arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

@Bill is probably right.  But, FYI, if you do need to reference a table multiple times in a SQL statement, you should alias them like this:

```
FROM school_rules sr1
JOIN school_rules sr2 on ...
```